# Event listeners on View element

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui

In a SwiftUI View we can have a Button element, and this button element has `onHover` event as well as an event which fires on a button click (called `action`), like this:

```
Button("MyButton1", action: {
            // EVENT1: executed on button click
        })
            .onHover { hovered in
                // EVENT2: executed on hover event
            }
```

Now I have my own UI element which I defined like this:

```
struct MyCustomSwiftUIView: View {

var body: some View {
    HStack
    {
        Button("MyButton1", action: {
                // EVENT1: executed on button click
        })
            .onHover { hovered in
                // EVENT2: executed on hover event
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now that I have `MyCustomSwiftUIView` defined, I want it to provide `onClick` and `onHover` events, just like the Button does. It should look like this:

```
MyCustomSwiftUIView()
    .onHover { hovered in
                // EVENT1: executed on hover event
            }
    .onClick {
                // EVENT2: executed on hover event
            }
```

**The question:** How can I add/implement these events on my own, custom made element `MyCustomSwiftUIView`?

*PS: I am new to SwiftUI, and imho the language is pretty messed up. This is the first language I am not able to learn on my own, and I am struggling with basic concepts which are so different from any other language I have ever experienced. For the first time not even Google can help me (hope I am not being too dramatic).*

Comment: "I am new to SwiftUI, and imho the language is pretty messed up" -- SwiftUI isn't a language, it's framework used with the language Swift. It's unclear from your post whether you're a beginner with Swift as well or just SwiftUI. " I am struggling with basic concepts which are so different from any other language I have ever experienced" -- SwiftUI is a declarative framework. If you were coming from using React, you'd probably find the concepts very similar. If you are coming from an imperative view/layout system, yes, it's likely very different.

Comment: Thanks for your question: I am completely new in the iOS development, which means complete beginner with both Swift and SwiftUI, but I feel much less capable with SwiftUI. E.g., I already am familiar with delegates from C# (in which I have 3+ years professional experience), and I have thought I can utilize that knowledge here, but it's pretty hard.

Comment: If you're coming at it from the perspective of a brand-new language (Swift) and a new layout paradigm (declarative/SwiftUI), it will definitely seem new, but I would disagree with the premise that it's "pretty messed up." Many people find *some* aspects of declarative UI to be much faster and simpler to work on, although sometimes more detailed or complicated work can be more challenging. I'd suggest you go through Hacking with Swift's "100 days of SwiftUI" course and the Apple SwiftUI tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to use modifiers like `.onHover` and `.onClick`, I'd suggest you pass the closures as parameters. That would look like this:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        MyCustomSwiftUIView(
            onClick: {
                //click
            }, onHover: { hovered in
                //hover
            }
        )
    }
}

struct MyCustomSwiftUIView: View {
    var onClick : () -> Void
    var onHover : (Bool) -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button("MyButton1", action: onClick)
                .onHover(perform: onHover)
        }
    }
}
```

Another example with built-in SwiftUI modifiers:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        MyCustomSwiftUIView()
            .onTapGesture {
                //click
            }
            .onHover { hovered in
                //hover
            }
    }
}

struct MyCustomSwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("My custom view")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much! How complicated is it to have  same effect but with usage of modifiers `.onHover` and `.onClick`? Also one more question: I am pretty sure question like this must have been already asked. How would you phrase it when searching on StackOverflow or Google?

Comment: If this answered your question, you can mark it as accepted with the green checkmark. In terms of using a modifier, it's likely not possible (or very complicated) with the way that you've constructed things (eg the `Button` inside). If you didn't want them to be the actions on the button, it's easy -- I've updated my answer to show an example.

Comment: In terms of the phrasing, again, it depends what you want. If you just want to know how to get a hover action, search "SwiftUI hover." If you want to know how to pass a closure down to a child view, search "SwiftUI closure as parameter"

Comment: Now I see that my example from the question is somehow ambiguous. I took a trivial example with only one button and two events for which there are built-in modifiers already available in the `View` struct. In reality I have many buttons in `MyCustomSwiftUIView` (edit, view, add, clone, etc.). Nevertheless, since the modifiers are, in my current understanding, only a syntactic sugar, I consider the answer complete. Still, if you find any resource which can help me to 'convert' my closures into modifiers, please feel free to add it to the answer or comment here.

Comment: So you have many buttons inside `MyCustomSwiftUIView` but you want them to all have the same `hover` behavior? Or `onClick` behavior? I'm not sure how the modifiers would work if that's not the case. I'm not sure what "convert" your closures into modifiers means besides what I've already given in my two examples.

Comment: Each of those buttons would have their own modifier. For example: `.onEditButtonClick`, `.onViewButtonClick`, `.onAddButtonClick`, `.onEditButtonHover`, .`onViewButtonHover`, `.onAddButtonHover`.

Comment: The easiest solution by far would be to pass them as closures. Unless there's an extremely compelling reason not to, that would be the right path. Otherwise, I suppose maybe you could use PreferenceKeys, but it would be an uphill battle with a ton of extra code for no benefit besides a very slightly different syntax.

Comment: I agree. This is more than I need. Thank you for your time and effort! I would only add a small note next to the second example (the one with modifiers) or remove it altogether as this is not the actual solution.

Comment: I don't think the second example needs a note -- it might be a valid solution to another user that finds this question. They can follow the comment thread to see exactly what worked for your specific case.

Comment: Found [this](https://github.com/GeorgeElsham/HidingViews/blob/main/Sources/HidingViews/View-hidden.swift) today and wanted to try to make my own extension/modifier `.onEditButtonClicked` but what I forgot is that `MyCustomSwiftUIView` is a struct and, therefore, immutable. For this reason I would not be able to attach my delegate function to it. I guess I would need to convert it to a `class` and then go through the pain of making `MyCustomSwiftUIView: ObservableObject` and its properties `@Published` as well as marking its usages with `@ObservedObject`. But would that pain end there?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. A View can’t be a class.

Comment: Didn't know that a View cannot be class. It seems that I'm going to waste my time on this until I either give up on Swift or find an answer (my brain won't allow me otherwise :D). If you have any hints please drop them here...

Comment: I wouldn't give up on Swift -- you're getting focused on an issue that literally just affects where a set of parenthesis goes. My advice would be to accept the tiny difference and focus on other functionality.